# AWS SNS - Multiple device push notification to mobile app instance

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

Currently i design push notification feature from my physical device to push message to IOS mobile app via SNS.

I have few number physical device(n times) and one mobile app (many instances). This means each of mobile app instance has one endpoint arn.

How can I design to push notification from device 1 to mobile app instance 1 and instance 2 but not instance 3? I know we may use topic where mobile instance 1 and 2 subscribed to the same topic arn. But i not idea how to design different mobile app instances listen to different topic once single mobile app deployed to app store.

Comment: Question: On these instances, will you be logging as the same user or as a different user? Pinpoint is an AWS service that enables you to segment your customers based on user/device level data - this might be worth looking into  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/segments-building.html

Comment: Hi Bommas, is the same user without required any logging. SNS solution is more preferred for me.

Comment: Hi JohnnyCc - SNS does offer a subscription filtering capability that may work for your scenario. You can specify a filterPolicy string with your criteria when you make the subscription and that will ensure that you only receive the messages for the device instance. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html for more information. Hope this helps.